# Pandas error: "None of [Index([' '], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas

For some reason, my code works when a list I am passing contains only integers. Using strings otherwise leads to the error in the title.

Here is my code:

```
def get_support(self, data, itemset):
    return data[itemset].all(axis = 'columns').sum()
    # I also tried: return data.loc[:, itemset].all(axis = 'columns').sum()
    # this function returns the number of True values (from .all()) of a given column or given set of columns
```

A sample of a data where this code works is:

```
  0 1 2
0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 0
3 0 1 0
4 1 1 1
5 1 1 0
```

Running `get_support(df, [0])` returns 4 and running `get_support(df, [0,2]` returns 2.

However, once columns are labeled, the code no longer works and outputs the error. I've checked the .csv file, and it's completely clean, with no spaces or extra stuff.

Sample of a data that will cause an error in my code:

```
  Red Yellow Blue
0 0   0      1
1 1   1      1
2 1   1      0
3 0   1      0
4 1   1      1
5 1   1      0
```

Where exactly am I wrong?

Edit: Thank you very very much to @osint_alex. The error is gone now, but there is unfortunately a newfound problem:

```
print(get_support(temp_df, ['A']))
print(get_support(temp_df, ['A', 'B']))
print(get_support(temp_df, ['A', 'B', 'C']))
```

Running this block of code only outputs this value for each: 9835, which is the number of rows the dataset has

I have attempted commenting out the other lines, and I get 9835 nonetheless. However, after checking the .csv file, I should only get 516 for `A` (unable to test for others).

As of now, I am still trying to solve it on my own, but the numbers are too all over the place I do not even where to begin.

Comment: I would rename `itemset` to `cols`, `col_names` or `col_idxs` to make clear what it's supposed to be. To reduce the possibility of bad input args.

Comment: @smci unfortunately, I cannot change variable names unless I were to create a new one because this was supplied to me. Thank you for the tip though, I think I can make good of use of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is going wrong is that you are using itemset to select the columns of interest in the dataframe. So if you want to use itemset to denote the indicies of the columns - which is what I assume you want to do if you want to always pass in numbers - then the get_support function needs to change to reflect this.

Essentially if you pass in numbers and the columns are labelled with strings, you'll get a key error because those numbers aren't the column names.

Here is a suggested revision:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3],
                   'B': [3,4,0]})
def get_support(data, itemset):
    cols = [x for x in data.columns if list(data.columns).index(x) in itemset]
    return data[cols].all(axis = 'columns').sum()

print(get_support(df, [0, 1]))
```

Out:

```
2
```

Comment: Hello! This kinda works but something is weird: I still get the same output for when the columns are unnamed (which means it's correct). When the columns are named, I do get an output but despite having three print statements, I only get one output. After omitting the other lines, I also get the same output for each. Unfortunately, I have no way of proving this as the data is really large.

Comment: Hey! Glad it's correct. Can't really help with the print statements though without seeing where they are in your code - can you edit your question to include?

Comment: Hello, it's edited now. Sorry there's a new problem, but you've been very helpful thus far. There's no need to assist with this as I myself do not even know where to start.

Comment: Hi again, apologies if I'm being rather bothersome, but if you the time, may I ask what made that work? I found out that the number being output (9835) is in fact the number of rows of the entire dataset

Answer (score 1):

You're going wrong here:

`data[itemset].all(axis = 'columns').sum()`

You can't `sum()` a string. You could run it through a data cleaning function first to make sure the list only has integers or floats.

Comment: `.sum()` here checks for the boolean values output by `.all()`, not strings nor integers

Comment: In that case, what is the boolean value of a string?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, `.all()` checks for the values under the column names, not the column names itself. The values are always integers. I'll edit the post for clarity.

Comment: Edited. Sorry for that.